# Automapper list to string ignore strange value

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a destination that is a List`<string>` and a source that's a string. I setup my config to ignore the List`<string>` field but I keep getting the List type as the string value

```
    class MyClass
    {
         string MyList {get;set;}
    }

    class MyClassDto
    {
          List<string> MyList {get;set;}
    }

//My cfg is like this
    cfg.CreateMap<MyClassDto, MyClass>().ForMember(x => x.MyList, opt => opt.Ignore());

//I've mapped this way
ObjectMapper.Map(input, dest);

//and this way
var destClass = ObjectMapper.Map<MyClass>(input);
```

It doesn't throw an error but it makes my string field this when its empty list:
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Can someone just explain why this is?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: What can't you test here? Create two classes, one w/ string one w/ List<string> ignore in cfg and then Map. You're need my entire source code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example you provide, it seems that the mapper you are using does not know of your configuration. In AutoMapper 9 you could use the configuration to create the mapper, e.g.:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<MyClassDto, MyClass>().ForMember(x => x.MyList, opt => opt.Ignore());
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var dest = mapper.Map<MyClass>(input);
```

Further information can be found in the [docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Setup.html).

Comment: I do you have the config as shown above. If it didn't know to ignore, wouldn't I be getting an error? That's what is strange. I don't get an error, it just stores the class type into the string field

Comment: Yes, you should get an error. What version of AutoMapper do you use?

Comment: I don't understand if I have ignore on, why would I get an error? It's 8.1.1

Comment: Do you really call `ObjectMapper.Map`? According to the [source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v8.1.1/src/AutoMapper/IObjectMapper.cs) `ObjectMapper` is abstract and further more its `Map` requires 3 additional arguments.